# When does the cycle's code execution stop in NodeJS Express?

Tags: node.js, express

After reading Node.JS Express documentation, I'm not clear about when the client cycle is finished after he requests something.

Does `res.json()`, `res.send()` and `res.render()` finish the *cycle* entirely? By entirely I mean: all the code execution in the server for that request. Or is it that the the client perceives a cycle finish by receiving a response from the server but the server continues to execute code?

For example, if I have this:

```
router.get('/home/about', function(req, res) {

     // code block #1
     // ...

     if (condition) {
        res.render('blah.ejs');
     }

     // code block #2
     // ...

     res.render('about.ejs');
});
```

If `condition` is true, I have a few questions:

1. Is `code block #2` executed?
2. Is `res.render('about.ejs')` executed?
3. If the answer to above question (2) is true, what happends with that response? because I'm pretty sure that the user will *receive* the response of `res.render('blah.ejs')`

Also, what changes if I write `return;` below `res.render('blah.ejs`)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function doesn't exit when you call `res.render` or any of the other examples you showed, but the pipe will be closed shortly after you call it so in most cases your example will result in an error that you tried to write to a closed pipe.

The best way to do what you're showing is something like this:

```
if(condition){
  return res.render('blah.ejs');
}

res.render('about.ejs');
```

This way when the code hits that 'return' statement, nothing else in the function scope will execute.

You could also (and many folks do) throw in a `return` statement before the second `res.render` call just to be explicit.